# Python equivalent to program in C

Tags: python, string, loops, sum, iteration

My goal is to translate the following written in C, into python, so I can evaluate the loop over a string of digits.  Originally, the objective takes a range from 0 to 9, gathers input for each iteration while also multiplying, and sums the entire range.  Last of all, determines the remainder after dividing by 11.

```
int checksum(char *str) {
    int i, sum = 0;
    for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
        sum+= (str[i] - '0') * (i + 1);
    }
    return sum % 11;
}
```

Comment: If you wrote that yourself in C, and you understand it, you should have no trouble translating it to Python. Go read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/#the-python-tutorial). You want to look at functions and for loops.

Comment: I'm in a python study group and the suggestion to the question by one of the members was submitted in C - a language I am not familiar with.  My reply, 'While I appreciate the suggestion, I'm not familiar with C.  Give a day to interpret the suggestion into Python.'  I'm at an impasse and sought help here.

Comment: My initial thoughts, construct a loop, iterate the range, ask for input per step, perform the math, sum the math and determine the remainder.  That is my process thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct (but not very idiomatic) translation of the code would look as follows, notice that I renamed some of the variables to avoid clashes with Python's built-in functions:

```
def checksum(s):
    c = 0
    for i in range(9):
        c += int(s[i]) * (i + 1)
    return c % 11
```

Another more Pythonic option would be to use generator expressions instead of explicit loops:

```
def checksum(s):
    return sum(int(e) * i for i, e in enumerate(s[:9], 1)) % 11
```

Comment: If you're going to go down that route then: `return sum(int(val) * idx for idx, val in enumerate(s[:9], 1)) % 11`

Comment: @JonClements Starting the enumeration in value `1` seems like a good idea. The `s[:9]` part I'm not so sure, I like that my version works for strings with lengths other than `9`. But the `int(val)` part will fail if the input contains characters other than digits (if that can be assumed then your suggestion is fine)

Comment: I put the 9 in as that's the entire extent of the OPs for loop - it can of course be removed or just make it `def checksum(s, n=None)`, then make it `enumerate(s[:n], 1)` or something. Also the OP wants to *evaluate the loop over a string of digits*, so I'd stick with `int` to make that explicit and get validation thrown in, otherwise stuff like `ord('!') - ord('0')` is going to have weird effects on the resut. Just my 2p though.

Comment: The assumption is input is an integer only, across the entire range, 0 to 9.

Comment: Oh, yes, use of int would be included.  Thanks for reminding me of that.

Comment: @CNO ok then, with those assumptions in place then Jon Clement's suggestions are spot-on. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Oh, got it!  Thanks, folks! (Checked)